# gif is not looking fine on WebView

Tags: android, webview, tablet, animated-gif

I added a gif image on html that is shown on a WebView.

**< img src="../../images/eula.gif"/>**

The gif itself sits in the assets folder.

On a mobilephone, everything looks to be fine, but when playing on tablet the gif is playing but looks very bad and is delayed and stuck.

Any idea how to work it out?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need scaleable images (but I'm not into this, I think its called SVG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying gifs on Android is very memory intensive, especially on larger devices such as tablets since each image is a lot larger than on a smaller device. Using a webview to display gifs works but it typically isn't the best way to do it. If you can, use a video instead of the gif (possibly using a service like [gfycat](http://gfycat.com/about)). As the video is compressed it uses a lot less memory than a standard gif and should display without any glitches.

Your other option for displaying gifs is to use a library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Again you may run into memory issues but it should be a lot better than using a webview.